# Need help using multiple return values in C

Tags: c

My task is to print lower case input as upper case, using return 0; if it is successful. If a non-lower case ascii character is inputed there is supposed to be an error message and I should use return 1; 
i've done most of the code but am having trouble with using the error message and using return 1; without it printing characters.

Here is my code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int main()
    char ()
{
  char letters[80];
  int i;
  scanf("%79[0-9a-zA-Z ]",letters);

  for(i=0;i<strlen(letters);i++)
  {
            if(letters[i]>=97&&letters[i]<=122)
            {
            letters[i]=letters[i]-32;
            }

  }
  printf("%s",letters);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Note: 1. You should change `%80` to `%79` because `%80` won't reserve a room for terminating null character. 2. Don't use `i<=strlen(letters)`. With this, you will read the terminating null character and it leads to printing "Error". Use `i<strlen(letters)`. 3. You should use `islower()` to check if the character is a lowercase alphabet if your teacher doesn't ban using it.

Comment: Are you allowed to make a function that passes the letters one by one and then returns the code 0 or 1? Then you can print the letter in the main body based on that return code (ie if 1 print error else print letter)

Comment: Use error message without printing characters? What do you mean by that?

Comment: **but am having trouble with using the error message and using return 1** Please explain your problem properly with expected output and current output.

Comment: Are u sure, that u are not allowed to make a extra function. U have to use the return value of the main function.Can u give the link to the question?

Comment: i mean when it prints error it still outputs the characters that were inputed- thank you for your help btw- so are you suggesting using islower() instead of stating the ascii codes in an if statement?

Comment: @rish1603 yes, I suggest using `islower()` because it is easier to read and write the code, and it is also valid in environments where ASCII code isn't used.

Comment: I think the program Won't print the input unless the input is "Error". http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/IGvcjUL5MW7E7dMY

Answer (score 0):

Just try this, take a look ..is that you are trying.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
int main()
{
    char sentence[100];
    int count, ch, i;
    printf("Enter a sentence \n");
    for (i = 0; (sentence[i] = getchar()) != '\n'; i++)
    {
        ;
    }
    sentence[i] = '\0';
    count = i;
    for (i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
         if(isupper(sentence[i])) {
                printf("Error");
                return 1;
         }
         else
           sentence[i] = toupper(sentence[i]);
    }
        printf("%s\n",sentence);
        return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I thought this might be the answer.

> My task is to **print lower case input** as **upper case**, using return 0; if
>   it is successful. **If a non-lower case ascii character is inputed there
>   is supposed to be an error message** and I should use return 1; i've
>   done most of the code but am having trouble with using the error
>   message and using return 1; **without it printing characters**.

So if the string inputted is all lowercase, you will uppercase them. In that case your code have worked. But if the string inputted is not all lowercase (for example: PROGRAMMING, pRogramMing, or pROGRAMMING), it should return some error message and return 1, without printing the string inputted. That's what I understand from your question. If that's the problem, here's my solution:

```
    char letters[80];
    int i;
    scanf("%79[0-9a-zA-Z ]", letters);

    for (i = 0; i<strlen(letters); i++){
        if (letters[i] >= 97 && letters[i] <= 122){
            letters[i] = letters[i] - 32;           
        }else{
            printf("You should only input lower case characters!"); //your error message here
            return 1;
        }       
    }

   printf("%s",letters);
   return 0;
```

Hope this is the answer to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the `<ctype.h>` library and the function `islower()` and the functino `toupper()`